# Mod rewrite .php to .xml in a directory and its sub directory only

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite .php file to .xml file in directory `rss/index.php` and its sub directories `rss/all/index.php` and `rss/main/index.php` and other `sub directories` only, I dont want to affect other directories in site with this rule.

i.e

```
root/rss/index.php to root/rss/index.xml
```

and

```
root/rss/all/index.php to root/rss/all/index.xml
```

I dont know about mod rewrite much, I trying this way but it does nothing.

```
RewriteRule   ^/rss/.xml$     $1.php [L]
also tried like this
RewriteRule   ^(rss).xml$     $1.php [L]
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?Site/rss/(.*)\.xml$ /Site/rss/$1.php [L]
```

This will make it so when someone requests `/rss/something.xml`, they will get served whatever is at `/rss/something.php`. These rules must be in the htaccess file in your document root.

Comment: I am getting 404 page not found error this way, page url `http://localhost/Site/rss/index.xml`

Comment: @TallboY In your question, you are asking for `root/rss/all/index.php to root/rss/all/index.xml`, are you sure you're not referring to the reverse?

Comment: I want to rewrite index.php to index.xml in rss/ and rss/sub-directories/ like you said /rss/something.xml, they will get served whatever is at /rss/something.php

Comment: @TallboY Ah, so your "root" is actually another directory, see the edit

Comment: still 404 error `The requested URL /Site/rss/index.xml was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request`.

Comment: @TallboY Do you have other rules? Are you sure you've turned `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: @TallboY You've added an `/all` in there, but you are not requesting a URI that has `/all` in it, therefore that rule *will not match* `http://localhost/Site/rss/index.xml`

Comment: Requesting this url `http://localhost/Site/rss/all/index.xml` also I have this working rule for sitemap in root directory. `RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]` which works on `http://localhost/Site/sitemap.xml`

Comment: I got it working like this `RewriteRule ^rss/(.*?)\.xml$ rss/$1.php [L]`